# Open iFrames in PhoneGap app while opening certain links in Mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, ios, iframe, cordova, mobile-safari

In past versions of PhoneGap, it was not possible to open iFrames within a PhoneGap app while opening other links in Mobile Safari.

We have read in a few places that this is fixed in 2.0, but it doesn't seem to work for us.

Is this possible in 2.0? If not, any ETA on when it will be possible?

Thanks!

Comment: By iframes do you mean the childbrowser plugin?

Comment: no, i mean iframes. like if we want to open a vimeo video without leaving the phonegap app.

Comment: Oh right, I only ask as I have to do something similar in my app, however I am using the Childbrowser plugin to achieve this. It basically lets you load a website without leaving the app.

Comment: interesting, you use the plugin inside the HTML5 code? or within objective-c code? if it's accessible from within the HTML5 code, it might help us.

Comment: Yep, it's called via Javascript within the html. Works great for me as I use to allow users to authenticate with an external framwork without leaving the app.

Comment: oh cool ... are you talking about this? https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser/. it seems like it only supports up to 1.5, though. we're on 2.0.

Comment: I think it will work up until 1.7, but I'm pretty sure some people have already modified it to work with 2.0 until Cordova gets updated.